# Trash tags in variables

Tags: categories, fields

While using the EE 3.0.2, I got this trash inside a variables, when using for example {exp:channel:categories} or {exp:channel:category_heading}

Ex:

```
{exp:channel:category_heading}
<h1> my free text here  {my_category_field} </h1>
{/exp:channel:category_heading}
```

But when I'm viewing my result, I see this:

```
<h1> my free text here <p>category field value</p> </h1>
```

There is a format field option in adding new field for categories, when I'm creating a field, I'm choosing no format at all, but when I'm going to edit the options of created field, I see the "XHTML" selected option there, which I can't change to something else. I think this trash "p" tag is going from here. What should I do to destroy this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug ([#21272](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21272/)) that's been fixed in EE 3.03.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do to destroy this bug?

... start by verifying it's a bug, and then report it to EllisLab. This is a common issue with EE (people finding the `<p>` tag inserts in formatted fields) but usually setting the field format to `None` fixes that. Did you edit the field and verify its setting?

Head on over to your

```
system/index.php?/cp/channels/fields/edit/XXX
```

page (`XXX` is your field_id) and verify that it's `Text formatting` is set to `None`.

Comment: Yes, just as I wrote. It's `admin.php?/cp/channels/cat/edit-field/1/2` for my bug, and yes it's a bug of new EE 3.0.2

Comment: Hrmm. I'll do some testing and see if I can recreate the issue. It's possible that a manual change to the database row for that field will fix the issue, but if it is a bug, I'm surprised I haven't run into it yet.

Comment: there are a lot of bugs for the new EE; For example, in yesterday-downloaded version I can't change the chosen template for the entry within the pages module options. It's changing only when I'm changing something else in a text of fields, for example.

Comment: Oy! I don't have EE 3 in the wild anywhere yet, just mostly 2.9+, so I'm only playing with it. I generally never adopt new full version changes for a long time, but I don't think they give new licence purchasers a choice, you have to use EE 3.

Comment: All EE3 purchases come with a valid EE 2.10.1 license and download.

Comment: Who said I'm working on something purchased. It's a CORE version. So I decided to use it for one fast project. 2.minor have no such a bugs, of course

Comment: @DerekHogue good to know. And I can recreate the issue; it's a bug apparently.

Answer (score 0):

So, until it's a bug, we need a common decision for it. I made this:

```
<h1>My custom text <?=strip_tags('{my_category_field}')?></h1>
```

and turned on PHP-parsing on closing for that template. Dumb, but this works for now.